# What is the library to be used to implement CoAP in ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, protocols, communication, arduino, coap

I am using Arduino IDE to program my ESP8266. I would like to send data from one ESP8266 module to other. So I would like to use CoAP for this communication. Is there any standard or good library to implement CoAP in ESP8266?

Answer (score 5):

There are no standards only RFCs for CoAP; all of them are accessible on the web:

1. [RFC 7228 - Terminology for Constrained-Node Networks, May 2014](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7228)
2. [RFC 7252 - The Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP), June 2014](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7252)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for this. I use this library for my arduino projects on a Wemos esp8266 based board.

https://github.com/automote/ESP-CoAP

Comment: Hi Ebleme, please tell us a bit about why this would be a good library to use. SE is not a good format for "once sentence and a link answers".